# Error on Redux Actions must be plain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux

I'm testing Redux on React, when I run npm run start in the console, I get the mentioned error message, this is my code, on index.js file, generated with 'npx create-react-app':

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const increment = ()=>{
  return{
    type:'INCREMENT'
  }
}
const decrement =()=>{
   return {
     type:'DECREMENT'
   }
}

const counter = (state = 0,action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
  }

}

let store = createStore(counter);

store.subscribe(()=>{
  console.log(store.getState())
})

store.dispatch(increment);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are dispatching a function to the store where as it should be an object. Try using this `store.dispatch(increment())`

Comment: Should be `store.dispatch(increment())`, note the "()" after increment. You're currently passing a function reference as an action.

Comment: @RobertVitoriano accept one of the answers below, Pranay Tripathi  was the first to spot it

Comment: I'll do it. It seems I have to wait a bit in order to do so.

Comment: @EugenSunic it's a typo, why not close it as such instead?

Comment: yea why not, will vote for closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dispatching a function to the store where as it should be an object. Try using this `store.dispatch(increment())`

Answer (score 0):

Store.dispatch accepts only a object as an argument. What you are giving here is a function. Use this instead
`store.dispatch(increment());`